# Number sequence issue Ax 2012?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have created a New number sequence named 'MyNumberSeq' using Number sequence form under Organization administration Module in AX 2012.
Now, I am using this number sequence in a form in some static field let's say 'MyNumberseqField' in Form 'MyForm' that will save the record in a table after pressing save button. 
If I am creating a new record, it is getting the number sequence in a specified field and data gets saved if I press Save button.
I am fetching number sequence as

```
MyNumberseqField.text(numberSeq::newGetNumFromCode("MyNumberSeq").num());
```

But My issue arises when I am closing this form by pressing cancel or by pressing Esc button(Let's say Number seq generated is MD-00001). Logically Number sequence which was generated should get free on this action.
The form closes as any normal form, **Now if am opening this form again to create new record, New number seq (MD-00002) gets generated instead of previous unused number MD-00001**.
Please suggest any solution for this or any other alternate way to create Number seq.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tick the

> Continuous

in Number sequence screen > Tab **General**

Answer (score 0):

Your form works as I would expect! The reuse of unused numbers requires special treatment which your form fail to do.

As explained in the [Number Sequence Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608474.aspx), use the `NumberSeqFormHandler` class to control the acquisition and release of numbers.

Comment: Bad thing to do, as you will have save the number somewhere.
But if you insist then dive in the methods of `NumberSeqFormHandler` to see what they do.